# Docker: user change in terminal prompt

Tags: linux, security, docker

I was just looking at the [Docker linode/lamp container documentation](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/containers/how-to-install-docker-and-deploy-a-lamp-stack), and encountered the following warning:

`sudo docker run -p 80:80 -t -i linode/lamp /bin/bash` ***Caution: This command also changes the terminal prompt to the root user within the new container.***

Assuming I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.3

RUN apk --update add \
      build-base python-dev \
      ca-certificates python &&\
    adduser -D -u 1001 not_root

USER not_root

CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

When I run some python code in this container (loaded from a volume and executed via `docker run`), it gets executed as the *not_root* user.

But when I then later do a `docker exec -it -u root that_container /bin/sh` in order to manually install a package, lets say for testing purposes, does the running container started with `docker start` or `docker run` still run as *not_root*? Or will that `docker exec` have changed the active user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, doing a `docker exec` doesn't modify existing processes running in the container:

```
bash$ docker run -u 1000 -d --name=top busybox top
fba16b1460ed53673002e81d8592f63dd1df1f90809b7046671b453bb59b1668

bash$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
fba16b1460ed        busybox             "top"                    5 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                                 top

bash$ docker exec -u root -it top /bin/sh
/ # ps -a
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    1 1000       0:00 top
    7 root       0:00 /bin/sh
   13 root       0:00 ps -a
```